# Scala - Two Lists to Tuple List

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Last year I had quite a bit of experience with standard ML, but I haven't done any real functional programming in about 10 months. Now that I'm on the Scala bandwagon, I'm having trouble finding an operation which I used extensively in standard ML when writing a compiler (although to be fair, this method may not have been a library method).

Basically, I have two lists:

```
List("a","b","c")
List(1,2,3)
```

And I want an operation that will give me a list of tuples like this:

```
List(("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",3))
```

Is there a standard Scala function I can use to get this result? (I think we called it a zip function in standard ML, but that seems to refer to something different when I was searching for Scala zip functions.)

Comment: Pretty sure `zip` is what you want, what made you think it is something different?

Comment: I found another post on Stackoverflow that gave a different definition of zipping, so I just assumed I was wrong. :/

Comment: Did you go to CMU too?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're right you can use zip:

```
val a = List("a","b","c")
// a: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

val b = List(1,2,3)
// b: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

a zip b  // beautified a.zip(b) 
//res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe this didn't turn up in any searches. I spent a good 15 minutes before this question searching and came up with nothing.

Comment: @GJK note that there is also method `.zipped` on tuple (if you want to zip 2 or 3 collections) which acts nearly the same: `(a,b,c).zipped.toList`

Comment: I actually did find that method, however it didn't work when I typed it into the terminal at SimplyScala.com, so I just assumed that it wouldn't work for what I needed.

Comment: What about zipping a longer Tuples like 5 or 6 collections together?