# Correct use of if condition with in map in scala

Tags: scala

I have two lists such that:

```
var pop=(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7)(4,7)))
var list=List(4,3)
```

What I want is:

```
List(List(4, List((1,3),(2,5))), List(3,List((3,7),(4,7))))
```

I used two maps with one if condition i.e.:

```
pop.map(y=>(list.map(x=>if(list.indexOf(x)==pop.indexOf(y)){(x,y)})))
```

but the result is:

```
List(List((4,List((1,3),(2,5))),()), List((),(3, List((3,7),(4,7)))))
```

I want to get rid of these empty elements i.e. in above statement I have `()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - Two Lists to Tuple List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423398/scala-two-lists-to-tuple-list). use `list.zip(Seq(pop._1, pop._2))`

Comment: What you say you want is, in fact, not a good thing. `List(List(4, List((1,3),(2,5))), List(3,List((3,7),(4,7))))` is type `List[List[Any]]`. Whenever you see type `Any` that's a pretty good sign that things are going off track and bound to get worse. Avoid it.

Comment: I want to have List[List[(Int,List[(Int,Int)])]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the following to achieve what your require

```
list.map(x => List(x, pop(list.indexOf(x))))
```

You should have output as

```
List(List(4, List((1,3), (2,5))), List(3, List((3,7), (4,7))))
```

You don't need `if` condition in the method that you are following and simply do the following

```
pop.map(y=> List(list(pop.indexOf(y)), y))
```

Comment: I wrote something wrong poip was like:    List(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7)(4,7)))

Comment: its still wrong as `,` is missing. I did the same `var pop=List(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7),(4,7)))` would you mind correcting that in the question?

Comment: @AnalKhan, is pop `List(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7),(4,7)))`? or `(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7)(4,7)))`?

Comment: List(List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7),(4,7)))

Comment: what if both **list** and **pop** are RDDs?

Comment: RDDs are a special kind of scala collection so should be same as well

Answer (score 0):

By using indexOf, you might introduce some Runtime Exceptions. You are better of doing a Zip like this:

```
val (listAFromTuple, listBFromTuple) = (List((1,3),(2,5)), List((3,7)(4,7)))
val list = List(4,3)

list.zip(Seq(listAFromTuple, listBFromTuple))
```

The result will then be:

```
List((4,List((1,3), (2,5))), (3,List((3,7), (4,7))))
```

And the resulting type is:

```
List[(Int, List[(Int, Int)])]
```

If your tuple is bigger instead of just 2 elements, you could probably first convert the tuple as a List and then zip:

```
yourListTuple.productIterator.toList
```

Comment: do you think idea of tuple will work for unknown number of elements

Comment: yes I want this:  List[(Int, List[(Int, Int)])] but for unknown number of elements

Comment: it will only work for 22 elements and i think i would have to manually mention those elements

Comment: but tuple only works for 22 elements if i have more than 22

Comment: If you have more than 22 elements, you are better off using a List or a Seq